# Linq left join when the class on the left side of equals can be null

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

Consider the following case:

**Classes**

```
public class Nested
{
    public Nested(int id){ Id = id; }
    public int? Id {get; set;}  
}

public class Pair
{
    public Nested NestedType {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}  
}

public class Match
{
    public int? Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}  
}
```

**Instances**

```
var p1 = new Pair();
p1.NestedType = new Nested(1);
p1.Name = "a";          

var p2 = new Pair();
p2.NestedType = null;
p2.Name = "b";

var p3 = new Pair();
p3.NestedType = new Nested(3);
p3.Name = "c";

List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>() {p1, p2, p3};

var m1 = new Match();
m1.Id = 1;
m1.Name = "AA";

var m2 = new Match();
m2.Id = null;
m2.Name = "BB";

var m3 = new Match();
m3.Id = 3;
m3.Name = "CC";

List<Match> matches = new List<Match>(){m1, m2, m3};
```

**Query**

```
var query = from p in pairs
            join m in matches on p.NestedType.Id equals m.Id into pm
            from m in pm.DefaultIfEmpty()                               
            select new
            {
               PairName = p.Name,
               MatchId = m != null ? m.Id : null
               MatchName = m != null ? m.Name : null
            };
```

The query will throw an exception on the `equals` statement line when `p.NestedType` is null.

What I'd like to achieve is this: When `p.NestedType` is null, a `null` value should be placed instead of it; It is as if `p.NestedType` is assigned but its `Id` is null. Can it be done?

EDIT: I have to use C# 5.0.

Comment: This is exactly what [C# null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) is for - `on p?.NestedType.Id equals m.Id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `where(...)` clause, you can prevent the null reference exception throwing in your case and check if this produce desired result for your cases:

```
var query = from p in pairs
            where p.NestedType!=null //Notice the where condition added
            join m in matches on p.NestedType.Id equals m.Id into pm
            from m in pm.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                PairName = p.Name,
                MatchId = m != null ? m.Id : null,
                MatchName = m != null ? m.Name : null
            };
```

**OR**

If you want to get all left side values always, for example, in your case if the result should look something like following, you can use [Null-Conditional Operator in C# 6.0 +](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn986595.aspx):

[image]

```
var query = from p in pairs
            join m in matches on p?.NestedType?.Id equals m.Id into pm //Notice Null-Conditional operator: p?.NestedType?.Id
            from m in pm.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                PairName = p.Name,
                MatchId = m != null ? m.Id : null,
                MatchName = m != null ? m.Name : null
            };
```

**OR**

If we need to do it in C# 5 as commented below, you can do:

```
var query = from p in pairs
            let nestedTypeId = (p != null && p.NestedType != null) ? p.NestedType.Id : null
            join m in matches on nestedTypeId equals m.Id into pm
            from m in pm.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                PairName = p.Name,
                MatchId = m != null ? m.Id : null,
                MatchName = m != null ? m.Name : null
            };
```

Comment: But this will eliminate the entire row where `p.NestedType` is null. I actually want the row to appear - it's a left join, after all.

Comment: I have to use C# 5.0

Comment: @HeyJude Updated answer for C#5. Hope that help you.